# How can I power an Arduino Uno using a 9V battery and a separate battery for raspberry pi 3

Tags: arduino, batteries, raspberry-pi, i2c

I want to power an Arduino using as separate battery power and raspberry pi with a separate battery

Comment: Hi Amit, please add more information about your current setup, your goal and maybe you can add schematic.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house or an on-line technical encyclopaedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and your own findings in considerable detail with any schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I use a 9 volt battery snap connector which connects the battery and barrel jack of the arduino uno(I am assuming that the arduino uno schematic is same as original one)  as shown [here.](https://rarecomponents.com/store/1532) Raspberry Pi 3b(original schematic) has a USB type power connector and you cannot use a 9 volt snap connector like arduino. It is  better to use a power bank or a wall adapter with power ratings of 5 V and 2 A.